# Solving a trig equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am trying to find an explicit solution to a trigonometric equation.  It is running for a long time and I didn't get any result, but Maple solves it quickly. Why ?

```
Solve[ γ == ArcCos[ Cos[α] Sec[θ] ] + ArcCos[ Cos[β] Sec[θ] ], θ]
```

Comment: If you're looking for a numeric solution please say so explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're after a symbolic solution you might try taking the `Cos` of both sides :

```
Solve[ Cos[ γ] == TrigExpand[ Cos[ ArcCos[ Cos[α] Sec[θ] ] + ArcCos[ Cos[β] Sec[θ]] ]],
         θ, Reals]
```

or

```
Reduce[ Cos[γ] == TrigExpand[  Cos[ ArcCos[ Cos[α] Sec[θ] ] + ArcCos[ Cos[β] Sec[θ]]] ],
        θ, Reals]
```

Comment: @chyanog You still didn't say, does the other software solve your equation symbolically ?

Answer (score 4):

Or like this:

```
Solve[Cos /@ (γ == ArcCos[Cos[α] Sec[θ]] + ArcCos[Cos[β] Sec[θ]] ), θ, 
 InverseFunctions -> True]
```